# How bad is JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm building a new website, So the idea is that I have 3 different types of products, they share some data and each one of them has its own data, I was thinking of creating a `product` table for the shared data and create 3 tables for each type's specific data. but soon i figured out that i couldn't load any product without doing a `JOIN` between the parent table and one if the 3 children. i'm not sure if i should go with this solution or i should create 3 tables and duplicate the shared columns between them.

what is the pros and cons for each approach?

which one should i follow?

Comment: In what way bad?  Database table joins are a fundamental part of querying a well structured database...

Comment: Joins are not bad. With proper indexing you can easily join 10 tables and still have great performance.

Comment: bad in a way that you have to JOIN each query to the db

Comment: You should go with your initial idea, there is nothing wrong with JOIN. Just make sure you have correct indexes on your tables.

Comment: `do not duplicate the columns in different tables`, as you said they are all products and you always want to have highly normalized tables, if you want to select from your producty another way just create 3 views on top of it for each type...(of course this depends largly on how big their `own data` is, but normally if you have entities that share most of their columns they would also be fine to go into the same table)

Comment: Thanks, should i create 3 foreign-key columns in the parent table for each child table ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Only one column for type is enough. And your PK column in each table should also be a FK to parent table.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic Thanks, but if it's 1 `type` columns how can I join ? or figure out which table i should join ?

Comment: Yeah joining from child to parent should be pretty straightforward but parent to child

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it really better to use normalized tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540136/is-it-really-better-to-use-normalized-tables)

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is "It depends on what you want to do".
Here are some advantages and disadvantages of using each of your approaches on different scenarios:

**Product table and 3 sub-tables per product type**

*Advantages*

1. If you have many non-type related queries, this is the hands down winner. For example, if you have a "category" list, where all products are shown regardless of their type, then this is a simple query - no joins, everything cool.
2. All your products being in one table is good for future customization, if you want to add another product type, that requires yet another table with data
3. No duplicate data. Nowhere.

*Disadvantages*

1. The only real disadvantage in this approach is actually your products. I mean: It would be much easier for you if you just didn't need that extra data per product type. So, you have to use `JOIN`. Nothing reall bad about that, though.

**3 Product Tables, each for a different product type**

*Advantages*

1. Well, there's an obvious advantage with this approach, if you always show your data per product type. I mean: if your database products are **pizzas**, **computers** and **pets**, chances are that you may never run a query on all 3 product types together. In that case, you may want to think of this approach.
2. Easier queries within a type.

*Disadvantages*

1. If you need to show all your products in a category view, you would have to run some serious `UNION` queries on this. That would be much worse than choosing `JOIN`.
2. `n` tables for `n` product types.
3. Possibly duplicate columns. Bad thing.

P.S.: The above do not take into consideration your specific needs. It is a generic suggestion, in generic conditions, without taking query performance into account.
Although, if your data is of reasonable size, you shouldn't be worrying about any of the two approaches (with obvious advantage on the first one).

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` is an integral part of a relational database. The only way it could be 'bad' is becoming a minor hassle in having to repeatedly create one in a query. `JOIN` is extremely helpful in eliminating duplicating data