# Normalize or Denormalize the MySQL tables in django

Tags: mysql, sql, django, normalization, denormalization

I am developing a Django Application which consists of 40 user fields. I have normalized by grouping related fields in to individual tables which resulted in 6 tables. But now I have another problem, if I want to retrieve the user information, I need to join 6 tables which is tedious task to write using ORM.

I am just wondering whether I can use a single table for those 40 fields or it will have any impact on the performance? I've read this post: [What's the better database design: more tables or more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59482/whats-the-better-database-design-more-tables-or-more-columns), but I need inputs on my particular scenario

Please advise on the normalization front.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you include (some of) your Models in the question? Are you using [Proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) or (regular) [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)?

Comment: I am not using either of them. I have simply created individual classes which have `OnetoOne` relationship with `auth_user` Model. Could you please advise on this context.